# How to find the maximum number of nodes in a GCP Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

In a GCP Kubernetes cluster is there a command to find out the maximum number of nodes? I have a Kubernetes cluster and need to identify if I can fit my pods to the nodes since there is a taint limiting one pod to one node.

If I want to have 50 pods, I need to know what limit there is on the number of nodes since one pod will match one node.

Answer (score 1):

In a GCP Kubernetes cluster there is no command to find out the maximum number of nodes

According to this official [doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/quotas#limits_per_cluster)

**Standard cluster**:

1)Maximum number of nodes per GKE  standard cluster is 15000 nodes

2)Maximum number of node pools in a cluster is 15 node pools

3)Maximum number of nodes in each pool is 1000 nodes.

**Note**:

- If you plan to run more than 2,000 nodes, use a [regional cluster](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/regional-clusters).
- If you want to run more than 5,000 nodes it requires lifting a cluster size quota. [Contact support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub) for assistance.

**Autopilot cluster**:

1)Maximum number of nodes per Autopilot cluster is 5000 nodes

**Note**:

- If you plan to run more than 1,000 nodes, use GKE Autopilot version 1.23 or newer.
- Running more than 400 nodes may require lifting a cluster size quota for clusters that were created on earlier versions. [Contact support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub) for assistance.

Comment: I hope the above information clarifies your queries. Could you please let me know if you have any additional queries and I am happy to assist further

Comment: I'm looking for the answer for a specific Kubernetes cluster, how to determine the limit of nodes on a specific cluster

Comment: In the question itself you mention GkE cluster.So,I have provided information from GKE official doc.could you elaborate on specific cluster means

Comment: I think the answer is something like:

gcloud container clusters describe myclustername --zone us-east1 | grep maxNodeCount

Comment: If you want to know how many maximum nodes are there in your existing  cluster

 To describe an existing cluster, run:  gcloud container clusters describe sample-cluster

Comment: Refer to this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/describe) for more commands  about cluster

Comment: If you run kubectl get nodes also you will get to know how many nodes are there in your cluster